# Android Parse Push Notifications is Slow?

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I just started developing with Parse's Push Notifications. I'm using them for pushing to Android right now and when I just started off, the notifications were delivered fast (instantaneous delivery).

However, as I'm sending more and more notifications to the same device - I'm noticing that it is taking about 10 minutes to deliver the notifications. Is this normal? If not, is this an issue with Parse or GCM?

Is there any way to "simulate" the notifications for development purposes so that they can be tested?

I'm generating the notifications from the REST API and have a Wifi enabled device.

Comment: GCM does not guarantees instant messaging nor it is used for strictly scheduled task. It completely depends upon gcm server. More over you can just add TTL or other parameters to it

Comment: If you using free it not better than gcm default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my experience in GCM or any other related service, should only be used if you have to push notification to some target devices i.e. to selected users from your database.

--For Higher scalability and maintainability 
You should **make background service** instead to fetch the notification and create a api for that, as there would be direct integration through your server, its is reliable fast and it has higher accuracy.
Whereas gcm does make a background service and hit gcm server and responds accordingly, but sometimes it misses the notification or delay as per the server load.

Comment: I need to send push notifications to target devices. However, writing my own Broadcast Receiver instead of relying on Parse's Broadcast Receiver seems to be much better. I switched over to Amazon SNS + own Broadcast Receiver and the notifications are now instant so far.